# Partition Identity Proof

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions

Hey guys I am trying to prove the following inequality.

> Prove that $p(n)\leq p(n-1)+p(n-2)$ for every $n \geq 1$. Here, $p(m)$ denotes the number of [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))s of $m$.

I worked on breaking it down into steps. I think that the best way to go about with this is in steps by considering:

(a) the number of partitions $n$ that have at least two parts equal to 1.

(b) then the other partitions.

Comment: I assume you don't know the pentagonal number theorem?

Which step do you have an issue with?

Comment: Sure, but keep in mind that you can prove this simply with PNT. For (a), construct a bijection: the bijection will take "partitions of n with a part equal to 1" to "partitions of n-1" by deleting that part. It has an inverse - adding a part that's equal to 1. You can show either injectivity and surjectivity, two-sided inverse, etc.

Comment: Ah, I see. Pardon if I'm being too low-level with this, I don't know your background :). A bijection is a map from one set to another that is both one-to-one and onto (maps to each element in the target set exactly once). In this case, our first set is "partitions of n with a part equal to 1" and our second set is "partitions of n-1". Now, if we delete that part equal to 1, we get a partition of n-1, right? Or if we added it back, we'd have a partition of n with a part equal to 1. So this definitely defines a map; try to show it's bijective (with the one-to-one and onto definition).

Comment: Oh alright! So how do we show that this bijection is injective and surjective?

Comment: (Terminology note: we want to show that the map is injective and surjective. "Bijective" means it IS injective and surjective; I'm only calling it that because I know it's a bijection.) Well, the definition of surjective is that everything gets mapped to. To show surjectivity, we want to pick an arbitrary partition of $n-1$ and find something that maps to it. This one shouldn't be too hard. For injectivity, we want to show that nothing gets mapped to twice. These fall out pretty quickly from the definition of our map; see if you can prove them (and write them up here if you can!)

Comment: Okay, I am sorry I have a hard time understanding the exact way to solve this. Do you mind solving (a) in complete form, so I can try to model after that for the other ones?

Comment: How is that an identity? Isn't an identity supposed to have an $=$ sign?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fairly straightforward injection from partitions of $n$ to partitions of $n-1$ and $n-2$.

Let $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\cdots+\lambda_k$ with $\lambda_1\ge\lambda_2\ge\cdots\ge\lambda_k\ge1$ be a partition of $n$ into $k$ parts.  If $\lambda_k=1$, then we have $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\cdots+\lambda_{k-1}$ as a partition of $n-1$ into $k-1$ parts.  If $\lambda_k\gt1$ and $k\gt1$, then we have $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\cdots+(\lambda_{k-1}-1)+(\lambda_k-1)$ as a partition of $n-2$ into $k$ parts.  Finally, if $k=1$, then we have $\lambda_1-2$ as a partition of $n-2$ into $k$ parts.

As it happens, this injection gives *all* partitions of $n-1$ but (in general, i.e., for $n\gt4$) only *some* partitions of $n-2$.  The key thing to note is that the mapping I've described truly is an injection -- that is, you don't get the same partition of $n-1$ or $n-2$ from two different partitions of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

As requested, I'll solve part (a) here. For completeness I'm including my comments above.

A bijection is a map from one set to another that is both one-to-one and onto (maps to each element in the target set exactly once). A bijection preserved cardinality (by definition), so if we have a bijection between the two sets, they have the same number of things in them. In this case, our first set is "partitions of n with a part equal to 1" and our second set is "partitions of n-1". Now, if we delete that part equal to 1, we get a partition of n-1, right? Or if we added it back, we'd have a partition of n with a part equal to 1. So this definitely defines a map; try to show it's bijective by showing it's one-to-one and onto.

For onto, consider a partition of $n-1$: say it's $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + ... + \lambda_k = n-1$. But then $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + ... + \lambda_k + 1$ is a partition of $n$ that has a part equal to one, and deleting that part equal to one sends us to the first partition. Since that partition of $n-1$ was arbitrary, every partition of $n-1$ is mapped to.

For one-to-one, imagine some partition of $n-1$ is mapped to by two different partitions of $n$ that have a part equal to one. But this obviously can't happen - all our map does is delete a single part (equal to $1$), so we can un-do it by adding a part equal to $1$. And adding a part equal to $1$ can't give us two different partitions. So nothing is mapped to more than once.